# HowTo: Azure DevOps YAML Iterate Projects in Solution

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

In XAML builds, there was a workflow activity which would return the list of projects in a soliton ***in the correct order for a build based on dependencies***

See: [XAML BuildSettings Class Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/gg419362(v=vs.120))

As we are migrating to YAML, I have not yet found a Task (or Script or....) that will accomplish this and allow me to write a for-each loop in my YAML...

Any suggestions appreciated.

Update 22-Nov: This is .Net 4.8 (and even some 4.7)

Comment: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow` is part of the client object model which was deprecated under .NET Framework and is not available with .NET (aka .NET Core). If you build the solution file, the projects will be built in dependency order. Is there a reason you can't build the solution?

Comment: What language is this? C# projects will automatically build in dependency order, you don't need to do anything special to accomplish it.

Comment: @DanielMann - (good to hear from you)... Yes, if I was going to "build" then that is true...but I want iteration so that further actions can be done on each of the projects *in the right order*.... Yes, I could modify project files with additional targets and props and configurations.... been doing that since forever.... but the question was specifically about YAML Build and built-in functionally [I can write a task that is based on something like MvsSln]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, if your projects are c#, they will be automatically build in dependency order when you use `DotNetCoreCLI@2`  task in your YAML pipeline.

You can set path to projects by the parameter `projects` .

Example(I have 3 projects in a solution.)

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

Note: `**/*.csproj` for all .csproj files in your solution folder.

Test Result:
[image]

Doc Referred:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Thanks.. but there can be many projects, some that are in other solutions, some that are not in solutions at all.. looking only for those in a specific solution to be returned by the iterator...